djangoCMS manage.py python.exe -m manage migrate failed
I am getting this error. I followed this documentation https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/01-install.html#install-django-cms-by-hand
(.venv) PS C:\django-py\.venv\scripts> djangocms tundra

Clone template using django-admin
django-admin startproject "tundra" --template https://github.com/django-cms/cms-template/archive/4.1.tar.gz
cd "C:\django-py\.venv\scripts\tundra"

Install requirements in C:\django-py\.venv\scripts\tundra\requirements.in
python -m pip install -r "C:\django-py\.venv\scripts\tundra\requirements.in"

Run migrations
python -m manage migrate

**CommandError: C:\django-py\.venv\scripts\python.exe -m manage migrate failed.**

After that I moved to Project folder "tundra" and ran the command
(.venv) PS C:\django-py\.venv\scripts> cd tundra
(.venv) PS C:\django-py\.venv\scripts\tundra> python.exe -m manage migrate  -  NO Error shown

by the runserver is not working
(.venv) PS C:\django-py\.venv\scripts\tundra> python -m manage runserver

It not showing any error but getting "Connection refused error"

If the second python -m manage migrate worked, it indicates that the database should have been created. You might also need to create a superuser (python -m manage createsuperuser). It seems that the runserver command fails for a different reason. Can you give more details?
